# What are the direct reaction products of the urease reaction (H. pylori) in vivo? How do I know this?

Tags: biochemistry

In the literature, several options can be found:

- [Benini et al. 1999](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0969-2126(99)80026-4): urea + H2O --> carbamate (H2NCOO-) + NH3 [+ apparently one proton somewhere]
- [Mazzei et al. 2020 (review)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00775-020-01808-w): urea + H2O --> carbamate + NH4+ [carbamate is then hydrolysed into bicarbonate and ammonia]; or: urea + OH- --> carbamate + NH3
- [Marcus et al. 2005](https://doi.org/10.1128/JB.187.2.729-738.2005): urea + H2O --> carbamic acid + NH3; carbamic acid is then hydrolysed to carbonic acid and another molecule of ammonia

Unfortunately, I don't have proper chemistry training and I can't find conclusive evidence for any of these options. Regarding carbamate/carbamic acid, a lot of other papers also write about the one, but draw the other in reaction schemes...
How can I know which reaction product of urease is the correct one?
I expect the reaction to take place at a pH of 7-8. I can't find the pKa of carbamic acid.

Comment: Without looking at the articles: are you considering products in vivo or in vitro? And under which conditions? There might be additional products that depend on the acidity of the solution and on other conditions (other enzymes etc).

Answer (score 2):

It's really dependent on the pH of the solution that the reaction is being performed in, which changes over time due to the alkalizing nature of urease. Consider that *H. pylori* must counteract its acidic environment in order to survive, which it does by raising the pH of its surroundings.

I found a pKa value for carbamic acid to be 3.92 [here](https://foodb.ca/compounds/FDB023195).

Also, consider that this reaction is enzyme-catalyzed, so exact products may not be completely dependent on pH. However, the products will likely still exist in a protonated/deprotonated equilibrium dependent on the local pH. At lower pH values, where urease may not be as effective, you would mostly see carbamic acid, while at higher pH values you would probably see carbamate (deprotonated carbamic acid).

I am inclined to say that at relevant pH (near 7.5 - 8.5, the optimal pH for urease), you would see the deprotonated form of carbamic acid, carbamate, and the protonated form of ammonia, which is the ammonium ion. The ammonium ion has a pKa value of around 9.25, which I found in another paper on this topic ([Wrobel et al., 2012](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349512006777)). As such, it would likely be protonated. Carbamic acid would be mostly deprotonated as its pKa is far lower.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! This makes sense from a chemical point of view. Now, I'm just a bit puzzled by how this reaction is meant to increase the pH in the periplasm of the bacterium, as this is usually ascribed to the generation of 2 NH3 molecules from one molecule of urea (e.g. [Sachs et al, 2011](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11894-011-0226-4), Fig. 1).

Comment: Ammonia is basic, so it follows that the pH would be increased.